# Calling third party APIS like amazon/ebay for getting product details using C++

Tags: c++, web-services, api, amazon-web-services

My requirement is - I have an application and need to get product details from amazon, ebay & few more websites for a product. Please let me know the process for getting the product info & also let me know how could i achieve this using C/C++ language. Does amazon support soap still? some where i saw its not supported. If soap is not supported then whats the next alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can use eBay API, and amazon API, and if you want to compare data and categories between the two (amazon and eBay), you can Try using [http://www.ecommerceapi.org](http://www.ecommerceapi.org/)
it's an API that combine between them

For example if you have one categoryId of eBay, Ecommerceapi can tell you what is the match for it in amazon

What ever you choose depends on your requirements of the project, API is simple technology that allows you to query the source over http.